# Joomla Random Image

Tags: php, javascript, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I have been searching a plugin/module for Joomla where:

1. Loads random image on page refresh
2. Have each image have their own URL
3. Has to work with Joomfish (multilingual)

Let me know if you have found any alternative component or module for this type of usability.

The reason why I wanna keep it as a module is I want the client to actually update it by themselves.

Comment: Awww... searching for Joomla plugins is not really programming related. Why not try the web apps site instead: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be pretty straight forward to implement on your own. If you want your clients tu update it by themselves you would need to create a component where they will be able to manipulate all the options. The core functionality would go to a module. Top this up with some configuration files for joomfish and you're done. Here are some references:

1. [Component development](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_1)
2. [Module development](http://www.joomladin.com/index.php/tutorials/34-module-development/70-introduction.html)
3. [Joomfish integration](http://www.joomfish.net/en/documentation/developer-docs)